# Cannot remove configured kernels in version 12.0

Tags: bugs, front-end, kernel

**Bug introduced in 12.0**

---

I have defined the settings of a  new remote kernel from Kernel Configuration Options in a MacOS machine. But the specification have a mistake and I need to redefine. When I try the new specifications do not get saved and upon opening Mathematica again it all stays as it was.

I wonder whether there a file somewhere on my home directory where this info is stored so that I can manually remove and start afresh.

Comment: Possibly init.m (for instance `FindFile["init.m"]` or http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html).

Comment: @MichaelE2 That would find the kernel `init.m`, but she need the FE `init.m` for this.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's why I included the link. Well, that and I didn't know whether it was an FE or a kernel problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is a major bug in version 12.0.0. Frankly, I am puzzled by why they didn't release a 12.0.1 to fix this ... for me it is a recurring major inconvenience.

The file in which the settings are stored can be found in this directory:

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "FrontEnd"}
```

Close Mathematica before editing it. First try `init.m`. If it contains only `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "VersionedPreferences"->True]` and nothing else, then you have version-specific preferences enabled and you must edit `12.0_init.m` instead.

Look for the `EvaluatorNames` option and make sure you don't break the syntax (i.e. fail to close braces, etc.)

I suggest you correct the specification directly in `init.m` instead of removing it and trying to re-create it with the GUI. Otherwise you may soon run into the same problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I have been literally wasting days on this!!! (editing the file with 11.3 and trying to  run it on 12.0)